# How can I find the main directory on my Android app?

Tags: java, android

I would like my Android app to find the main directory on my tablet's internal storage.   The furthest I can get is reading the contents of the "user.dir", but that seems to be the root directory and the listing there is too immense to find what would be considered the DOS equivalent of C:\

I am listing the code snippet I use to read the directory to show I can access the internal storage, but somewhere I'm not able to do it correctly.

```
 workingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
 File f = new File(workingDir);
 File[] files = f.listFiles();
 for (File inFile : files) {
 if (inFile.isDirectory()) {
```

Thanks

Comment: What is "the main directory"?

Comment: @CommonsWare , by "main directory" I mean whatever the equivalent of a Galaxy Tablet of C:\.

Comment: Um, well, Android isn't Windows. Hence, I do not know if you mean [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/13/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/14/storage-situation-external-storage.html), [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/15/storage-situation-removable-storage.html), or something else.

Comment: @CommonsWare yes I meant internal storage.  in fact, if you were to open the "My Files" explorer that comes with Android the top option on my tablet is called Internal Storage, and it lists all the viewable folders from within.   So when I say C:\, that's what I mean.  I would like to be able to access that directory and create/delete directories and files.    I just have no idea how to tell my app to go there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> in fact, if you were to open the "My Files" explorer that comes with Android the top option on my tablet is called Internal Storage, and it lists all the viewable folders from within

That is what the Android SDK refers to as [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/14/storage-situation-external-storage.html). You can find the root of that via `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`. However:

- Don't put things directly there, just as well-written Windows programs haven't put stuff in `C:` for the past couple of decades. Use `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` for standard locations (e.g., downloads directory), or use `getExternalFilesDir()` on `Context` for a location that is unique to your app.
- You need to hold `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and/or `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions, including setting up runtime permissions for use on Android 6.0+ devices.

Comment: thank you, this was driving me crazy.  For some reason non of the three beginners books covered this, and I saw the word "internal" so I just assumed.

Comment: @PlasticProgrammer: Yes, the varying names given to storage causes no end of confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to give a look at the android [Environment documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getRootDirectory())    and access internal storage root/main directory with this `Environment.getRootDirectory()`

Comment: I can use the environment options, but my goal is to be able to get to the main directory (assume C:\, but on Android Tablet) and create a directory there.  Sadly am unable to find out how.